# Setting up PostgreSQL 13 log-shipping replication between 2 CentOS 8 vagrant boxes,

Tags: postgresql, ssh, vagrant, centos8, log-shipping

I've been trying to set up log-shipping replication between 2 CentOS 8 vagrant boxes, but I have two problems I just can't seem to find the answer for:

1.,I've followed the official pgsql documentation to set up continuous archiving on the master, but it doesn't archive any wal files, even though there are some of them in the pg_wal directory and their archive status is ready. It checked the logs and it does seem to try to archive them, but there's always an error.

This is the error for 'scp %p vagrant@10.0.0.201:/test/%f':

> scp: /test/000000010000000000000001: No such file or directory
> 2021-01-21 16:52:05.851 UTC [4635] LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
> 2021-01-21 16:52:05.851 UTC [4635] DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: scp pg_wal/000000010000000000000001 vagrant@10.0.0.201:/test/000000010000000000000001

and this is the error for 'cp %p /test/%f' :

> cp: cannot create regular file '/test/000000010000000000000001': No such file or directory
> 2021-01-21 16:52:09.415 UTC [5862] LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
> 2021-01-21 16:52:09.415 UTC [5862] DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: cp pg_wal/000000010000000000000001 /test/000000010000000000000001

In the first example I'm trying to scp wal files to my standby server and in the second one I'm simply trying to cp them into a test folder I created in the `/var/lib/pgsql/13/data folder`. I checked with `ls -la` and postgres should have permission to write in the folder: `drwxr-xr-x.  2 postgres postgres`. I've tried other archive_commands too, like the one in the documentation: `'test ! -f /mnt/server/archivedir/%f && cp %p /mnt/server/archivedir/%f'`, and it logged the same error as the cp one above.

[I've also checked the archiver, with `select * from pg_stat_archiver;` but it just showed that archivation failed a lot of times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEzdX.png)

Here are my posgresql.conf settings:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
max_connections = 100
password_encryption = scram-sha-256
shared_buffers = 128MB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix
wal_level = replica
max_wal_size = 1GB
min_wal_size = 80MB
archive_mode = on
archive_command = '' #as mentioned above
archive_timeout = 60
log_destination = 'stderr'
logging_collector = on
log_directory = 'log' 
log_filename = 'postgresql-%a.log' 
log_truncate_on_rotation = on 
log_rotation_age = 1d
log_rotation_size = 0
log_line_prefix = '%m [%p] '
log_timezone = 'UTC' 
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'  
timezone = 'UTC' 
lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8' 
lc_monetary = 'en_US.UTF-8'
lc_numeric = 'en_US.UTF-8'
lc_time = 'en_US.UTF-8'
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

I've also changed pg_hba.conf to allow host to connect to the db, so I'll include that as well just in case:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256                                                                                                      host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

2., My other question is more related to linux, or possibly vagrant. Since I'm trying to set up log-shipping, I need the wal archive to be somewhere the standby can read the files, which is why I'm trying to scp the files over. I generated ssh key-pairs with ssh-keygen for both vagrant, which is the default user when I ssh into the box and postgres, and then added both public keys to both vagrant(`/home/vagrant/.ssh`) and postgres(`/var/lib/pgsql/.ssh`) users' authorized_keys list. The problem is that while I can ssh into the vagrant user on the standby server with both users from the primary, when I try ssh into postgres user with either it says `postgres@10.0.0.201: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`

I've tried checking what the problem might be using `ssh -v postgres@10.0.0.201` command and it works perfectly, up until the point the server should accept the key:

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:DgndkBcWnrG7q0VkLNUA+hjsHGO+HWyUQRTrffl8NWg
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
postgres@10.0.0.201: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

My question is why this might be, and if I even need to ssh into postgres user, or I can just simply save it somewhere with vagrant user and make that folder possible to read to postgres user somehow(I've read about maybe using shared folders, but I haven't found any good guides on how to do that yet).

Here are the vagrantfiles, in case they are needed:

primary:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "generic/centos8"
    config.vm.hostname = "pgsrv1"
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "pgsrv1"
      vb.memory = "1024"
    end
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 5432, guest: 5432
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.200"
end
```

standby:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "centos8/standby"
    #config.vm.box_url = "/vagrant/centos8_standby/package.box"
    config.vm.hostname = "pgsrv2"
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "pgsrv2"
      vb.memory = "1024"
    end
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 5434, guest: 5432
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.201"
end
```

Sorry if they are really noob questions, but I'm fairly new to linux and vagrant and I've been stuck on this 2 weeks and nothing I find online seems to work at all.

Edit:

I made a completely new vagrantfile and after setting it up copied it with `vagrant package` and now archive command works as it should(still no clue what the problem is on the original box).

I configured ssh again however and it's still the same, I can easily ssh into the vagrant user and so I was able to scp the wal files over with archive_command, but still can't ssh into postgres.

So now my only question remains if anyone has any idea why I'm not able to ssh into postgres, or if there's a simple workaround, like making the folder I scp the wals into somehow readable to postgres user.

Edit1:

It turns out that it was selinux doing something magical, some configuration that allowed ssh conns to vagrant user and not to postgres, so the issue was solved by turning it off :).

Comment: Does the directory '/test' exist on the intended recipient machine?  The command you give will not create that directory for you if it does not already exist.  Note that since the path starts with a slash, this is at the root level of the filesystem, not relative to any (unspecified) path.

Comment: Yeah, it does, in fact I tried out scp to see if it works outside of the archive_command, by creating a simple .txt file and scp-ing it over and that worked perfectly.

Comment: The ssh server is not going to tell the ssh client very much about why it failed, as that could aid an attacker.  Look in the server's sshd log file for more information (possibly after turning up the logging level)

Comment: I tried looking at the log file as you suggested.
These are the logs generated when I log into vagrant user, which works:


`Jan 22 20:57:14 testserver1 sshd[10135]: Accepted publickey for vagrant from 10.0.0.202 port 45872 ssh2: RSA SHA256:fdcHqf0O54f6brRRbHfR2JVF9eORyM8++9PoD558MdM` and
`Jan 22 20:57:14 testserver1 sshd[10135]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user vagrant by (uid=0)`

And when I try to ssh into postgres user:

`Jan 22 20:59:59 testserver1 sshd[10291]: Connection closed by authenticating user postgres 10.0.0.202 port 45880 [preauth]`